# How to install Helm Umbrella Charts pulled from remote repository

Tags: kubernetes-helm, umbrella

I have an umbrella chart uploaded in a remote repository and am trying to install it. How do I get it pulled down and ready to install?

I've tried `helm fetch repo/umbrellachartname --untar` which untared it but with nothing in any of the folders.

This seems incorrect and I simply want to install it and all its dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install a helm chart, use `helm install <repo name>/<chart name>`, i.e.

```
helm install repo/umbrellachartname
```

in your case.

You can also first fetch it and then run `helm install .` in the untarred directory.

If the directories are empty as you describe, I would think the uploaded chart is broken.